# How can I install gcc 7.2.0 for centos7?

Tags: gcc, centos7

I have a machine with Centos7 that has the version of gcc 4.8. From the site https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-7.2.0/ download gcc-7.2.0.tar.gz,  what should I do to install this version of gcc?

Comment: I guess you want to build it. See this great article: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Building from the source code did solve your problem?

Comment: I have already downloaded the file mentioned, build and install the necessary dependencies and build and install the gcc7, following the instructions in the article, thanks again